# Gulp watch not emitting event object

Tags: gulp, gulp-4

Gulp (4.0) throws the error `"Error: Invalid glob argument: undefined"` when I attempt to `gulp.src` the path of a changed file obtained from `gulp.watch`. Both this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./web/**/*.html')
        .on('change', function(file) {
            gulp.src(file.path)
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./output'));
        });
});
```

and this syntax variant:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./web/**/*.html', function(file) {
        gulp.src(file.path)
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./output'));
    });
});
```

yield the same result.

Logging file.path before the `gulp.src` also outputs "undefined".

**To reproduce:**

`npm install -g gulp@github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0`

and create a `gulpfile.js` containing:

`const gulp = require('gulp');`

followed by either of the examples.

My understanding is that this is the way in which the changed file's path should be accessible [as per the docs](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpwatchglob-opts-fn), so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That documentation is all kinds of wrong. E.g it talks about [`gaze`](https://github.com/shama/gaze) events, but `gaze` is no longer used to watch for file changes in gulp 4.0; it has been replaced by [`chokidar`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar).

Concerning your problem the docs are wrong about the way you have to access the file path. The `.on('change')` callback function is not passed an `event` object, so there is no `.path` property.

Instead the file path is passed as a string, so your first example should look like this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./web/**/*.html')
        .on('change', function(file) {
            gulp.src(file)
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./output'));
        });
});
```

The callback function in your second example doesn't receive a path at all. It's passed a `done` callback, in order to facilitate task execution via `gulp.series()` or `gulp.parallel()`.

Comment: Vielen Dank! That is indeed the issue; many thanks for taking the time to explain. Hopefully this serves as a resource for others with the same headache.